# unable to create a new project in django got error. Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

unable to create a new project in django got error.
it display error

> django-admin startproject someproject
>   Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'

i have django version 1.10.6
an python27 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your Python environment variable (open windows explorer, right-click on 'this pc', 'advanced system settings', 'environment variables') do not add any space character.

If you have Program files, you may want to replace

```
C:\Program files\\...
```

by

```
C:\PROGRA~2\\...
```

Finally reopen your terminal and try again your

```
django-admin startproject someproject
```

Good luck,